# Error : Third party action method not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using one third party tool. I have inherited its controller with MVC controller
{

```
public class ReportController : ReportServiceBaseController
{

}

public abstract class ReportServiceBaseController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadDocumentInfo(LoadDocumentInfoRequest request);
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadDocumentMapInfo(LoadDocumentMapInfoRequest request);
}
```

}

When I make call to "LoadDocumentInfo" method it give an error of not found.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you use ReportController to call LoadDocumentInfo method ,but you have not implement this method in Controller ,so i think first you have to implement it in your controller and than try to call that method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ahmad, Actually I am using third party dll for reporting and LoadDocumentInfo is implemented in it. I just shown meta data.